# Sending POST request to a Drupal module file

Tags: node.js, drupal

I'm trying to send a post request to a Drupal .module file from node.js. My problem is that the module file is never executed as php by Apache when the request is made, so instead of getting a response from php, I get the literal code (inside the .module file) as a text string.

I tried enabling .module to execute as php (not sure the security implications) by putting the following in .htaccess:

Addhandler application/x-httpd-php .module

(and virtually every other combination of that command I could find)

But no luck.

I know the post request sent by node.js is perfectly fine because it works when sent to .php files on the same server. I just can't get it to work within a Drupal module. I want it to be sent to a Drupal module because I want to take advantage of Drupal's API (going to be doing a lot of modifications to drupal user tables).

How do I send a post request to a drupal module, programmatically, from node and read its response? I know how to send it to a simple .php file, but not to a drupal module.

Comment: Show us the code your trying to execute.You have got the module in a fully working drupal site haven't you? What version of drupal?

Comment: Drupal v.7. The code i am trying to execute simply returns the post request back:   echo json_encode($_POST);

Comment: this is confusing. Where are you sending your post request to? You would need your module to set a path (hook_menu) that would then execute your function and return your response. Post your module code in the question

Comment: I'm sending the post request directly to the module file (the .module file). I've heard this answer before, but haven't heard an explanation. How would one send a POST request to drupal which would send it to the module and execute some code? that's really all I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: i think i figured it out. my problem was that I didn't understand the post requests were treated as paths in Drupal, and therefore, should be handled by hook_menu. I've now got a path registered with hook menu, am sending post requests to it.

Answer (score 1):

You create a [menu](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiDu-_wkd7TAhVGMI8KHV33ACoQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.drupal.org%2Fhook_menu&usg=AFQjCNFZY6pB1fNMZB8d8HG-dzf60Hylpg&cad=rja) in module file.

```
function mymodule_menu() {
    $items['post-link'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_abc_view',
    );
    return $items;
}
```

and then send the post request on that menu link through Node.js.

YOURSITENAME/post-link?data1=abc&data2=def 
 And then fetch the post data on those menu call back function to use [drupal_get_query_parameters()](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwib8Pulkt7TAhUJvI8KHbO4C7sQFgghMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.drupal.org%2Fapi%2Fdrupal%2Fincludes%2521common.inc%2Ffunction%2Fdrupal_get_query_parameters%2F7.x&usg=AFQjCNGCdIGU5aAiye0GKcjfDGcCxJ0lSg) function.

```
  function mymodule_abc_view() {
    // ...
    $parameters = drupal_get_query_parameters();
    print "<pre>";
    print_r($parameters);
    print "</pre>";
  }
```

it may be help for you.

Thanks,